# Creating a custom random variable

Tags: bash, random

I want to create a custom variable or command that can be called on like $RANDOM, but for strings. I have a script that creates a random string, using /dev/urandom . The script produces a randomly generated string each time the script is run.

```
#!/bin/bash

rando=$(head -100 /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 | fold -w 15 | head -1)

echo $rando
```

If I create an alias or environmental variable that calls on the script, it will produce only one variation of a random string until a new bash sessions is created. How can I make it so it will create a new variation of the random string in the same bash session?

Comment: Wrap it up in a [function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) in your `.bashrc`. Then every time you call it, the code will run.

Comment: Huh? The variable `$rando` is of course the same until you change it, but calling `dd` etc again will create a new value each time. Or are you asking how to make a function around this code?

Comment: `RANDOM` is a special built-in parameter; you can't define your own variable whose value changes every time you expand it.

Comment: This might work, too: `tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 15`

Comment: Worked like a charm @JNevill . This accomplished what I wanted to do. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As replied by JNevill, you can place it as a function in your bash profile :

```
function RANDOM(){
    rando=$( head -100 /dev/urandom | tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 | fold -w ${1:-15} | head -1 )
    echo $rando
}

RANDOM
RANDOM 4
RANDOM 40
```

Output

```
17oxDRkl2O1c9iz
vfgZ
4xlVNyINrBj8XT04nkQWIVOTHAV51eVxtVNEyRW0
```

I added an optional first argument so you can control the length of the string as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to accomplish, thank you! So this works because it calls on the function each time to create the string, rather than a variable being declared by the script when bash starts up, right? Why does an alias that calls on the script not work then?

Comment: Im not sure of your actual implementation. But for what you describe, you seem to be confusing environment variables with aliases. if you do this : *export RANDOM=$(SOME COMMAND CALL HERE)* the value of RANDOM will always be the same. While if you create an alias you always get an actual command being executed. Anyway, I *almost* always end up using functions instead of aliases. Code can be more complex and easier to read. So if in doubt, I would recommend to default to functions most of the time and avoid aliasing.

Comment: Starting to use functions more in my scripts, as they do make everything look a lot cleaner. Thank you for your insight, marked your answer as the solution. :)

Comment: I'd recommend simplifying this by removing the `rando` variable and `echo` -- just have the pipeline produce output directly.